# Conditional arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to create a function that restricts the arguments passed. `dpr` and `w` should not be both passed at the same time. Here's my attempt:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDq6De6DuAXOhAK4C2ARvOgL6iSyKoYAiADnLugCafFkqNeiFBQAnuwwBlOCgDOMKAB4AKgD50AXm6k4AG2LyocSAHM66AGRYwPKAAsA8nA5w1m0GMkZMdxy5uHtroqugwAB6wEDzyWOgA-PHEbgDc6F4gCKQQKFBgAPYQ6AgFcORIULIKSmrhUTAxcdgAPuhu6gAUBez5RfLE1YoqGgCUuJkioKXllUNKnXh6hugA5AD066sANLz86ACMdKOp02UVVXLDi%20jLxBtbu0SHx6dZ53NXC0sG95s7BGIB12fDgQNe6E26HkDgKpH0PBKSDA%20kyQA)

```js
interface W { w: number }
interface Dpr { dpr: number }

type Srcset<T> = { url: string } & WidthOrDpr<T> 

type WidthOrDpr<T> = T extends W ? W : Dpr; 

function formatSrcset<T extends W | Dpr>(options: Srcset<T>) {

}

formatSrcset({ url: '//', dpr: 1 }); // ok
formatSrcset({ url: '//', w: 1 }); // ok
formatSrcset({ url: '//', w: 1, dpr: 1 }); // should fail
```

I would like to avoid [function overloads](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading).

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid the thing that's for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most concise code, but what if you forced `dpr` / `w` to be undefined by defining two interfaces for the different arg options? Something like this:

```js
type Args1 = { dpr: number, w?: undefined };
type Args2 = { dpr?: undefined, w: number };

type Srcset<T> = { url: string } & (Args1 | Args2);
```

Comment: Not concise indeed, but this is the closest solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`type-fest`](https://npmjs.com/type-fest)'s [`RequireAtLeastOne`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/require-at-least-one.d.ts)

```
// code from sindresorhus/type-fest

type RequireAtLeastOne<
    ObjectType,
    KeysType extends keyof ObjectType = keyof ObjectType,
> = {
    // For each `Key` in `KeysType` make a mapped type:
    [Key in KeysType]-?: Required<Pick<ObjectType, Key>> & // 1. Make `Key`'s type required
        // 2. Make all other keys in `KeysType` optional
        Partial<Pick<ObjectType, Exclude<KeysType, Key>>>;
}[KeysType] &
    // 3. Add the remaining keys not in `KeysType`
    Except<ObjectType, KeysType>;
```

In your case

```
type Args = RequireAtLeastOne<{
    url: string
    dpr?: number
    w?: number
}, 'dpr' | 'w'>


function fn({ url, dpr, w }: Args) {...}
```